# How to save a file in geojson using open street map in android studio?

Tags: java, android, geojson, osmdroid, osmbonuspack

I need to save my points within a geojson, but I do not know how

I already tried using a KML, but I could not because I do not know if I need to use a new class or not

As I do not know if I should put within a new class or within the onCreate, it ends up always giving error in the end and I can not solve it for lack of information and contact with this area, as I am new, please help me, It's a college job.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //onde mostra a imagem do mapa
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Essa é para poder utilizar as permissões
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        osm = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapaId);
        osm.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        osm.setUseDataConnection(true);
        osm.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        osm.setClickable(true);
        osm.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                String[] permissoes = {Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                requestPermissions(permissoes, PERMISSAO_REQUERIDA);
            }
        }

        osm.setMapListener(new MapListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(ScrollEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onScroll ()");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onZoom(ZoomEvent event) {
                Log.i("Script()", "onZoom ()");
                return false;
            }
        });

        mc = (MapController) osm.getController();
        GeoPoint center = new GeoPoint(-5.1251, -38.3640);
        mc.setZoom(14);
        mc.animateTo(center);
        addMarker(center);


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            // .
            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        MapEventsOverlay mapEventsOverlay = new MapEventsOverlay(this, this);
        osm.getOverlays().add(0, mapEventsOverlay);

        // Aqui adiciona a escala do mapa
        ScaleBarOverlay scaleBarOverlay = new ScaleBarOverlay(osm);
        osm.getOverlays().add(scaleBarOverlay);

        kmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    //    kmlDocument.parseGeoJSON(geoJsonString);

       /* this.mLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(new GpsMyLocationProvider(ctx),osm);
        this.mLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
        osm.getOverlays().add(this.mLocationOverlay);*/

        this.mCompassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(this, new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(ctx), osm);
        this.mCompassOverlay.enableCompass();
        osm.getOverlays().add(this.mCompassOverlay);

    }
```

This is my code, I made it up to that point. How do I add the GeoJson inside it, should I put it inside the onCreate? Should I create a new java file to deploy the library or from version 6 do I need to do this?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have no idea what you actually want to do. In particular, which " points" do you want to save?  I see no data that would be a candidate for saving in your example. You have only some general osmdroid library setup - and this library is supposed to display a map (=a bunch of images called tiles) and some additional overlays over the map (pins and so on). If you want to extract some data from openstreet map, this library will no help you at all.

Comment: hello, this library I'm using is showing me the map and it's really still not saving anything inside a GeoJson, so I humbly ask you to help me get GeoJson into it

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: What I want to do is save my coordinates (Latitude and longitude), so I can save this information inside a GeoJSON

Comment: And those coordinates come from where? Do you mean  the current position/location  of you ( your device ) from GPS?

Comment: When I click on the screen I create a new point, these points I want to save them inside a geoJson. This point is the starting point, that is, where the map starts